# Azure web role - Diagnostics not working on particular instances

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles, azure-diagnostics

I am using azure sdk 2.9.5. I have a web role with 3 instances and all the instances seem to log the the diagnostics data fine. Once i scale it out to 10 instances, only 4 instances are emitting diagnostics data and the remaining are not emitting any iis logs , perf counters, wadlogs etc. Any pointers on how to trouble shoot?